# Is this an acceptable proof that $x^2<y^2$ when $x$ and $y$ are positive reals with $x<y$?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

The question is

> Prove the following statement:
>
> Suppose $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $x$ and $y$ are positive. If $x < y$ then $x^{2} < y^{2}$.

Proof:

Suppose there is a value $r$ between $x$ and $y$ so that
$$x < r < y \tag1$$ where $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ r > 0$. Therefore,
$$x<r \Rightarrow x^{2}<xr \tag2$$ and
$$r<y \Rightarrow yr < y^{2} \tag3$$
Moreover, if we multiply equation $(1)$ by $r$, we get
$$xr < r^{2} < yr \tag4$$
Combining equations $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$, we get
$$x^{2} < xr < r^{2} < xy < y^{2} \tag5$$
Therefore, $x^{2} < y^{2}$. $\blacksquare$

If necessary, we can even define $r=$ $x+y\over{2}$

Is there anything wrong with this approach? I'm aware of the normal method of direct proof.

Comment: What benefit is there in introducing $r$ ?

Comment: It is logically sound, so from that point of view there is nothing wrong.  It is unnecessarily complicated because of the introduction of $r$, which adds a number of steps and hides the fundamental idea.  You use the same idea as in $x^2 \lt xy \lt y^2$ but with two more values and a number of lines.  That is "wrong" because it makes the reader work more.

Comment: You can also use that $f(x)=x^2$ is and increasing function in $\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín - How does that work exactly?

Comment: @DanielBeetham You know that $f(x)=x^2$ is an increasing function for positive numbers, right? 
Then, in an equality, if you apply the functions both sides, it holds that if $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$, otherwise if it's decreasing, if $x<y$ then $f(x)>f(y)$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Right. So that's enough for a proof Fabrizio?

Comment: Indeed. From my point of view it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to introduce $r$; to wit:

$x = x; \tag 1$

$x < y; \tag 2$

thus

$x^2 < xy; \tag 3$

also,

$y = y; \tag 4$

from (2) and (4),

$xy < y^2; \tag 5$

combining (3) and (5):

$x^2 < xy < y^2. \tag 5$

$OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is like proving $1 < 3$ by showing $1 < 2$ and $2 < 3$. You basically end up proving the result along the way except you wrote down a bunch of extra steps.

As soon as you have $x^{2} < xr$, you have the result immediately from the hypothesis:
$x^{2} < xr < yr < y^{2}$ as none of them are zero.

Just in case you didn't prove this concisely using a direct proof, you need to prove that $(y+x)(y-x)=y^{2}-x^{2} > 0$ where $y,x > 0$ and $y-x > 0$ which is clear since $y+x > 0$.