# Suppose x and y are positive real numbers. If $ x < y $, then $ x^2 < y^2 $

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

Suppose x and y are positive real numbers. If $ x < y $, then $ x^2 < y^2 $

My proof is:

> Suppose $ x < y $, As both numbers are positive, squaring both sides doesn't change the symbol of the inequality, therefore $ x^2 < y^2 $

However, it seems too easy.

I'm aware of another, more elaborate, proof that follows:

> Suppose $ x < y $, then $ 0 < (y - x) $. As both numbers are positive $ x+y $ is positive and we can multiply both sides of the equation by it without changing the sign. Thus, $ 0 < (y - x)(y+x) = y^2 - x^2 $, and $ x^2 < y^2 $.

The second one is convincing enough but I'm new with proofs and I'm wondering if the first one is good enough or if I should prove as well that "squaring both sides of inequality doesn't change the symbol of the inequality"

Comment: This *really* depends on your axioms and propositions and level of the text.  The first one claims that if both numbers are positive "squaring both sides doesn't change the symbol of inequality".  But why do you know that?  Did you prove that? Or is it something the book gave you.  ... also I'm not sure what that statement means.  It sounds like it is just rewording what you need to prove.  You are trying to prove that if $x <y$ positive $\implies x^2 < y^2$ and you are using "If $x,y$ are positive squareing mantains inequality.  Isn't that just the exact same thing?

Comment: To my mind the simplest and most covincing prove would be:  If $x < y$ and $x$ is positive then multiplying both sides by $x$ yields $x\cdot x < x\cdot y$.  And as $y$ is positive then multiplying both sides of $x < y$ by $y$ yields $x\cdot y < y\cdot y$.  So we have $x^2 = x\cdot x; x\cdot x < x\cdot y; x\cdot y < y\cdot y; y\cdot y = y^2$.  By transitivity we have $x^2 < y^2$.

Comment: Thanks, @fleablood. That one is very good.

Comment: Guillerminho77's comment about monotonicly increasing $f(z) = z^2$ makes me think this more geometric analytical proof is enlightening.  If $x <y$ the let $h = y-x > 0$ so that $y = x + h$.  Then $y^2 = (x+h)^2 = x^2 + 2hx + h^2 = x^2 +(2hx + h^2)$.  As $h>0; x> 0$ we know $(2hx+h^2) > 0$ so $y^2=x^2 + (2hx+h^2) > x^2$.  In math there is always more than one way to do it.

Comment: Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information. Make the body of your questions self-contained. One good reason for this is that some interfaces to MSE (like the Android interface) don't display titles properly. As regards the maths in your question: faced with problems involving formulas like $a < b$, it is often helpful to replace them by $b - a < 0$.  If you do this and use the formula $y^2 - x^2 = (y - x)(y + x)$ you arrive at the second proof you mention, which is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rob, I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the first proof is that your justification is exactly the same thing you're asked to prove.

A formal axiomatic mathematical system has its ways of building up more complicated proofs from simple theorems. In such a system, this proof would likely be an early step of describing important properties of the $<$ relation. (Probably the proof would look like the one involving $y^2-x^2$, or like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3992418/2236) $x^2 < xy < y^2$ proof.)

Probably your context isn't a formal system like that, but when writing proofs, especially proofs of simple and well-known facts like this, we sometimes write as if we were in some unspecified system where the proofs should come in some order within some imagined list of the common and useful theorems, to avoid making statements which are essentially circular reasoning. Or at least, if we know that theorem X is used in the usual proof of theorem Y, and we're asked to prove theorem X, we would avoid assuming or using theorem Y in the proof of X.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to doubt the validity of the first attempted proof. In particular, the statement "since both numbers are positive, squaring both sides doesn't change the symbol of the inequality" is dubious. To see why, consider that I could just as well argue that since $2>1$ and $1$ and $2$ are positive, we know that $\cos(2)>\cos(1)$. Of course, this is not the case.

To put it differently, there is no reason, *a priori*, to believe that if $a>b>0$ then $a^2>b^2$; it is certainly not  true in general that if $a>b>0$ then $f(a)>f(b)$ for some function $f$. The fact that in the special case of squaring, the statement *is* true, is precisely what you are trying to prove.

Now, whether or not a proof is valid depends on which axioms (assumptions) and theorems you have at your disposal. Here, I will make the following two assumptions about the total order $<$ on $\mathbb R$:
\begin{align}
x<y &\implies x+z<y+z \tag1\label1 \\[5pt]
x>0 \text{ and }y>0 &\implies xy>0 \, . \tag2\label2
\end{align}
If you are familiar with some abstract algebra, then you should recognise that these two assumptions, together with the field axioms, are equivalent to declaring that $\mathbb R$ is an *ordered field*.

Now for the proof: assume that $x<y$, where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary positive real numbers. Then, $0<y-x$, by $\eqref1$. Hence, $y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$. Since $0<x$, we have $y<x+y$, and since $0<y$, it follows that $0<x+y$. Thus, $y^2-x^2$, being the product of two positive numbers, is also positive, by $\eqref 2$. Hence $y^2>x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if the first one is good enough

The first one is just a restatement of what is to be proved.  Also recall the definition of what it means for a real function to be strictly increasing:

$$f \text{ is strictly increasing in } D \iff (\text{for all }x,y\in D: x<y \implies f(x)<f(y) )$$

Thus, squaring both sides of $x<y$ yields $x^2<y^2$ prodvided $x\mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing, which is the case as $x,y > 0$.

**However**: Using that $x\mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing on $\Bbb R^+$ is circular, because the claim "$x<y\Rightarrow x^2<y^2$" is just the statement that $x\mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing over the domain in question.

Thus, use a different function like $f_\alpha:x\mapsto \alpha x$ which is strictly increasing iff $\alpha > 0$:

$$\begin{align}
0<x<y &\implies (x^2 = f_x(x) < f_x(y) = xy\ \text{ and }\ yx = f_y(x) < f_y(y) = y^2) \\
&\implies x^2 < xy < y^2
\end{align}$$
which conclused the proof.

What's left to you is to prove that $f_\alpha: x\mapsto\alpha x$ is strictly increasing provided $\alpha > 0$.

Your second proof is fine.  It goes directly to the axioms of an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Total_order): $a,b>0\Rightarrow ab>0$ used with $a=y-x$ and $b=y+x$.